# Make footer bottom consistently based on content

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to make my footer look at bottom of page based on content. I tried and applied many css. and many ways but still I am facing one issue.

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 0 25px;
    background: #1e1e1c;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
body, html {
    font-family: 'sairaregular';
    font-size: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

If I give css like this for some content page its located at bottom like this.
[image]

So its not at end of page its just located at bottom when opens page. How can I fix thiss. if someone suggest me solution for this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://codepen.io/takeradi/pen/MyYqKX

Comment: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/

Comment: https://alligator.io/css/css-grid-holy-grail-layout/

Comment: i gave html positive:relative and min-height as 100%. now its showing at bottom., but in somepages content will be taken dynamically its angular in that case its taking some where up before content ends., and also if footer goes ends there some space is coming how should i fix that

Comment: if you want to fix it to bottom irrespective of  content then use `position:fixed`

Comment: if i give fixed it will always stay at end even when i scroll up and down., but i want it to be at end of page when scroll ends at that point i need to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

#footer {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="page-container">
    <header>
      A header?
    </header>
    <div id="content-wrap">
      Main area
      <footer id="footer">
        This is a footer
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the desired layout is use `flex` property for parent `div` and provide a `height` property.

HTML markup -

```
<body>
  <div id="page-container">
    <div id="content-wrap">

    </div>
    <footer id="footer">

    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS properties -

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#page-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;

}

#footer{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #DDD;
  margin-top:auto;
}
```

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/n3rd/pen/pozZQpj).

In the html section, try uncomment the `p` tags to visualize the behavior when the content overflows the visible page.

Comment: Yes I saw this answer., and in your example its working fine. But in my design still im facing white space between content and footer. I am using in angular

Comment: Can you create a minimum reproducible issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/). It'll be easier for us to help you